# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined , while using transitionToRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined". This is when i am using transitionToRoute in a controller.
The transitionToRoute function in controller,

```
     transitionToRoute: function() {
         // target may be either another controller or a router
         var target = get(this, 'target');
         var method = target.transitionToRoute || target.transitionTo;
         return method.apply(target, arguments);
     },
```

here the target variable is being assigned a view instead of controller or router. I don't know if this is a issue or am i using transitionToRoute in a wrong way. Need help here.

EDIT:
The above function can be found here, 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/v2.0.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/ext/controller.js#L41

EDIT:
In the above function, it calls get function with a controller object as "this", looking for "target" key in it.
When i log "this.target" in transitionToRoute it prints a route class, but if i log the same variable in get function i get a view class.

I have no clue how this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
transitionToRoute: function() {
     // target may be either another controller or a router
     var target = get(this, 'target');
     var method = target.transitionToRoute || **this.target.transitionTo;**
     return method.apply(target, arguments);
 },
```

Comment: Thats's the function of ember, I guess i don't won't to edit that. And I assumed, you suggested to remove that code. I tried that but view class only has tranistionTo function. So it threw an error saying function is not there.

Comment: Even if this code change would be an option, how would this even change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the controller's transitionToRoute function is getting its route and calling route's transitionTo function. 
So, as a workaround we can directly get route in controller and call transitionTo()

```
//inside controller
this.get('target').transitionTo(arguments);
```

But still would love to know why this is happening.